# How to delete a docker network that does not exist?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-swarm, zombie

I have a docker swarm configuration with 3 nodes. There is a network that sits on only one of the nodes. On that particular node, `docker network ls` shows the network, `docker network rm [network-id]` says "**Error response from daemon: network ... not found**" while `docker network inspect [network-id]` show the network and it looks pretty good (Scope: swarm, Driver: overlay). Exactly like one that i have created test-wise in parallel to compare it with.
Any idea anyone? How can I get rid of that network- zombie?

Comment: Does "docker network prune" affect the zombie network?

Comment: No it doesnt I do experience the same problem. Can reproduce but not on purpose. Happens after a while. docker network ls <network> shows `id` `name` `overlay` `swarm` but `docker network rm <id> or <name> gives: "Error response from daemon: network `id` not found

Answer (score 24):

> How can I get rid of that network- zombie?

Please try the following.

```
docker network inspect <id> or <name>
```

Under Containers you see all the containers that are still connected to the network

```
docker network disconnect -f <networkID> <endpointName> or <endpointId> try both
```

Next remove all unused networks

```
docker network prune
```

Fixed the problem for me ;)

Comment: The container listed in `docker network inspect` isn't in `docker container ls`. But if I do a disconnect with the endpoint name, this seemed to help.

Comment: I had to give the --force flag because without it, docker complained that the listed containers didn't exist.

Comment: @RyanFox Geoffrey Wieseman I updated my answer. Thank you for the input. We just experienced that we require the <endpointName> or <-f> flag as well sometimes for reasons ... :)

Comment: nothing worked for me, only a "/etc/init.d/docker restart" removed the zombie network

Comment: It worked for me, but I had to use the endpointName instead of endpointID

Comment: Thanks for the help, but although there were actually some containers listed in the containers section after doing `docker network inspect`, the command `docker network disconnect` (even with the `-f` flag and both endpoint name or ID) resulted in an error (the endpoint does not exist). Only a `sudo service docker restart` worked for me.

Comment: I experienced that recently as well but one must admit we have RHEL 7.5 and Docker is quite outdated so more like our fault.

Comment: What if `"Containers": {},`?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue for my dev environment (unrelated to swarm) while experimenting with connecting containers across docker compose instances. I tried stopping / starting compose, killing containers, removing images, pruning networks, and restarting docker numerous times and in a variety of sequences, yet nothing worked.

Finally I ran the following on the problematic instance while the other compose instances were up, which *did* work:

```
docker system prune
```

This removed (per the warning):

- all stopped containers
- all networks not used by at least one container
- all dangling images
- all dangling build cache